# Evaluating $\frac{1}{a^2-ac-ab+bc} + \frac{2}{b^2-ab-bc+ac} + \frac{1}{c^2-ac-bc+ab}$ for $a=1.69$, $b=1.73$, and $c=0.48$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

An interesting question on algebra:

> If $a=1.69$, $b=1.73$, and $c=0.48$, find the value of$\\$
> $$\frac{1}{a^2-ac-ab+bc} + \frac{2}{b^2-ab-bc+ac} + \frac{1}{c^2-ac-bc+ab}$$

By substituting the values, I got the answer, but I want to know if there is any short algebraic way because putting the values was a lot time consuming.

Thanks.

Comment: Apart from computing $ab, bc, ac$ first and then using them, I have no other ideas. Why would you think there's a shortcut? What's the source of the problem?

Comment: Try factoring the denominators.

Comment: it's actually from a competition @Deepak

Comment: @Blue Good catch. But in the time one takes to factorise and do the algebra, it might be easier to just punch in the values on a calculator. Again, this is a limitation of the way the question is presented, even something as basic as whether a calculator is allowed is not specified.

Comment: @arnav-de Are you allowed a calculator?

Comment: @arnav-de There is also a contest math tag, which may be appropriate. I'll add it.

Comment: nope we aren't allowed @Deepak

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression $L$ is equal to
\begin{align}
L &= \frac{1}{(a-b)(a-c)}+\frac{2}{(b-c)(b-a)}+\frac{1}{(c-a)(c-b)} \\
&= \frac{-(b-c)-2(c-a)-(a-b)}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)} \\
&= \frac{a-c}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)} \\
&=- \frac{1}{(a-b)(b-c)} \\
\end{align}

and it's easy now to calculate $L = 20$.